# Monospace Swing Text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, ascii-art, monospace

I wrote a program that takes a picture and creates an ASCII representation (ASCII art). At first, I wrote the ASCII string to the console, but now I have a JLabel that holds the text. However, the JLabel output is irregular and is not as even as the console output. I tried using a monospaced font (Droid Sans Mono) as the font in the JLabel since it's what I use for the console output, but the output is still irregular. Is there a better way to specify a monospaced font in Swing/JLabel?

Here is the method I use to create the JLabel:

```
public JLabel formatLabel(){
    String l = "<html>";
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j+=patchSize){
    for(int k = 0; k < width; k+=patchSize){
        l+=imageArray.get(j).get(k);
    }
    l+="<br>";
    }
    l+="</html>";
    return new JLabel(l);
}
```

And the line I use to specify the font:

```
label.setFont(new Font("Droid Sans Mono", Font.PLAIN, 6));
```

EDIT: I changed the JLabel to a JTextArea and that works alot better. The only problem is even with a tiny font, the frame is usually outside the screen. But I have a method that changes the number of pixels to sample, which would make the output smaller.

Comment: Try using `label.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 6));` to see if that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the html font tag to specify the font for your text.

> By specifying HTML code in a label's text, you can give the label various characteristics such as multiple lines, multiple fonts or multiple colors. If the label uses just a single color or font, you can avoid the overhead of HTML processing by using the setForeground or setFont method instead.

```
public JLabel formatLabel(){
String l = "<html><font face=\"verdana\" color=\"green\" size=\"12\">";
for(int j = 0; j < height; j+=patchSize){
for(int k = 0; k < width; k+=patchSize){
    l+=imageArray.get(j).get(k);
}
l+="<br>";
}
l+="</html>";
return new JLabel(l);
```

}

Comment: I was still editing my post to include the OPs code to include the font tag following the html tag.

Comment: Is that html line known to work? The html tag is already inside quotes, so the font name and font color would not be contained within the string.

Comment: @user1420750 Your quote specifically says that you can avoid the overhead of HTML processing by just using `setFont`. What the OP already has should work. Also, you forgot to escape your quotes.

Comment: @Jeffrey I agree with the fact that if its a single font then the OP has got to go with the regular style of what he has already done (to avoid the overhead of html processing with java code). Since he asked about another (better) way I think this is another alternative to achieving the same output though with slight overhead. And thanks for the catch that i forgot to escape my quote.